# LinkAssemblies fails after upgrading to MVVMCross 4.0

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have just updated a large Xamarin project from MVVMCross version 3.5 to 4.0. I have fixed all namespace issues and bugs, but I am stuck with this bug:

```
The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Xamarin.Android.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 
'System.Boolean Android.OS.BaseBundle::GetBoolean(System.String,System.Boolean)' 
(defined in 'MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null') from 'MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved. --->     
Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: 
Failed to resolve System.Boolean Android.OS.BaseBundle::
GetBoolean(System.String,System.Boolean)
```

I have added `MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging.*` to linkerConfig.xml, but to no avail.

Comment: Do you reference any packages that depend on MvvmCross besides the plugins?

Comment: Only other MVVMCross plugins.

Comment: @GoldnArms Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @jkh I have put this issue aside for now, will try again if I get any new pointers.

Comment: @GoldnArms It seems to be resolved in my project after changing the Compile using Android version and Target Android version fields to Android 6.0 (API level 23 - Marshmallow).

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue. The MvvmCross dlls are build to version v6.0 for android. I noticed the following output tab (My logging is set to verbose).

> warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.dll (v6.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v5.0).

When I changed the projects to Android 6.0 I still received the linker error. When I opened the project file in a text editor I noticed that was defined twice. Once in the global property group set to 6.0 and once in the Debug property group set to 5.0. I removed the following line from the Debug property group and the issue went away.

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v5.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to switch on verbose logging in your build.  For iOS specify verbose logging by adding:

```
-v -v -v -v
```

To the extra build parameters textbox.  Then run the build again.

```
For Android you can do this in the Visual Studio Tools -> Settings -> Xamarin -> Android settings -> Xamarin Diagnostics.
```

You will probably identify that some packages are of different versions and will cause this linking issue.

You will find some clues to the issue using verbose logging.  I have only mentioned the verbose logging for this platform as its the platform I have most experience with at the moment.

This is the best answer I can offer as this issue can be caused by a truly massive number of issues and will be individual to each solution.